# Css3 donut menu

Tags: css, user-interface

Hi I would like to implement a donut menu like this one http://dribbble.com/shots/610433-Wheel-Nav I know there is a simple way to do a donuts in css3.

```
.doughnut { 
    border: 50px solid #f00;
    border-radius: 100px;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}
```

BUT of course this only make the donut without any elements inside of it. I'm wonder if it's anyway to do it only with css3, any ideas of how to start? if is not possible with only css i will jump into javascript area...

Comment: Probably absolute positioning.

Comment: You could take a look at http://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/jfqtv and http://codepen.io/tgrant54/pen/lBHwK for some examples.

Comment: you can "fake" a donut using a circle inside other(with the color of the background) or learn some svg. lets say you have a site with FFF color background, just insert a small circle on a big one with FFF bg, abuse of border-radius and creativity.

Comment: Yes, it's pretty easy. I'll make a demo to reproduce that image.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My attempt to reproduce that image with CSS:

## [*live demo*](http://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/Bzuti)

**Result**:

[image: result]

**HTML**:

```
<ul class='menu circ-menu'>
  <li class='menu-item'>
    <a href='#'>☊</a>
  </li>
  <li class='menu-item selected'>
    <a href='#'>☁☀</a>
    <ul class='menu submenu'>
      <li><a href='#'>☂</a></li><!--
      --><li><a href='#'>☁</a></li><!--
      --><li><a href='#'>☃</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class='menu-item'>
    <a href='#'>✦</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**:

```
.menu { padding: 0; list-style: none; }
.menu a {
  display: block;
  color: #666561;
  font: 900 2em/3.2 monospace;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0 1px white;
}
.circ-menu {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  margin: 1em auto;
  padding: 5em 0 0;
  width: 20em; height: 10em;
  box-shadow: 0 .5em .5em -.5em;
}
.menu-item {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  left: -50%; bottom: 0;
  width: 20em; height: 20em;
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}

/* === style the menu items (slices) === */

/* three slices making up half a circle mean that a slice is going to have a central_angle = 60deg */
.menu-item:first-child {
  transform: skewX(30deg) /* 90deg - central_angle */;
}
.menu-item:nth-child(2) {
  /* rotate by the value of the central angle multiplied with how many slices are before */
  transform: 
    rotate(60deg) /* 60deg = 1*central angle */
    skewX(30deg) /* 90deg - central_angle */;
}
.menu-item:last-child {
  transform: 
    rotate(120deg) /* 120deg = 2*central angle */
    skewX(30deg) /* 90deg - central_angle */;
}

/* === contents of the menu items === */
.menu-item > * {
  position: absolute;
  top: 55%; left: 55%;
  width: 90%; height: 90%;
  text-align: center;
}
.menu-item > a {
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 .2em #aaa497, 
    0 0 .5em .2em black;
  transform:
    skewX(-30deg) /* unskew */
    rotate(-60deg);
  background: #f8f4ef;
  background: 
    radial-gradient(transparent 39%, #f7f3ee 40%);
}
.selected > a { z-index: 1; }
.selected > a, .menu a:hover {
  color: #e96429;
}
.selected > a, .menu-item > a:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 .2em #e96429, 
    0 0 .5em .2em black;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(60deg, #e96429 31%, rgba(247, 243, 238, 0) 33%),
    linear-gradient(-60deg, #e96429 31%, rgba(247, 243, 238, 0) 33%),
    radial-gradient(transparent 39%, #f7f3ee 40%);
  background-size: 100% 26%,  100% 26%, 100% 100%;
}

.submenu {
  z-index: 0;
  transform: 
    skewX(-30deg) /* unskew */
    rotate(-60deg)
    translateY(-5.25em);
}
.submenu li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  border-top: solid 1px #666561;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #666561;
  width: 3.2em; height: 3.2em;
  background: #f7f3ee;
}
.submenu li:before {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%; height: .2em;
  background: #666561;
  content: '';
}
.submenu a {
  line-height: 2
}
.submenu li:first-child {
  border-radius: .3em 0 0 .3em;
  border-left: solid 1px #666561;
}
.submenu:after {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 2.5em; left: 50%;
  margin: 0 -.6em;
  width: 1.2em; height: 1.2em;
  transform: rotate(-30deg) skewX(30deg);
  background: #666561;
  content: '';
}
.submenu li:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 .3em .3em 0;
  border-right: solid 1px #666561;
}

.circ-menu:before, .circ-menu:after {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: -7.071em; left: 14.645%;
  width: 14.142em; height: 14.142em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: '';
}
.circ-menu:before {
  bottom: -5em; left: 5em;
  width: 10em; height: 10em;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 .75em black, 
    0 0 .5em .2em #f7f3ee;
}
.circ-menu:after {
  bottom: -1em; left: 9em;
  width: 2em; height: 2em;
  box-shadow: 0 0 .4em dimgrey, 
    0 0 0 .75em #e27447, 
    0 0 .4em .75em dimgrey, 
    0 0 0 2em #f7f3ee, 
    0 0 .4em 2em dimgrey;
  background: #f7a480;
}
```

The idea is pretty simple. You start with a list structure, just like you would do for every menu.

```
<ul class='menu-circ'>
  <li class='menu-item'><a href='#'>boo</a></li>
  <!-- the other list items -->
</ul>
```

### Explaining the basic idea

You give the container `.menu-circ` `position: relative` and you absolutely position its children (the menu items) such that one of their corners is at the centre (of `.menu-circ`). Then you set the transform-origin for `.menu-item` to be in that corner.

In this case, I've chosen the bottom right corner to be at the centre (`transform-origin: right bottom` is equivalent to `transform-origin: 100% 100%`), but it doesn't really matter, you can choose whichever corner you want to put at the centre and set the `transform-origin` there.

You then need to decide on the value of the [**central angle**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_angle) for each slice that a menu item forms. In this case, it was easy - there were three slices for half a circle, half a circle means `180deg`, so assuming that I want 3 equal slices, the central angle for each is `180deg/3 = 60deg`.

Having decided on that, you now need to make the sides that meet at the centre of the parent (right and bottom sides in this case) form an angle of `60deg`. You do that by applying a skew transform, the skew angle being `90deg-60deg = 30deg`:

```
transform: skewX(30deg);
```

But this still leaves all the menu items in the position of the first one. So for all the menu items but the first one, you also need to rotate the by the value of the central angle times how many items there are before. This means that you'll have:

```
.menu-item:first-child { transform: skewX(30deg); } /* no items before */
.menu-item:nth-child(2) { transform: rotate(60deg) /* 1*60deg */ skewX(30deg); }
.menu-item:nth-child(3) { transform: rotate(120deg) /* 2*60deg */ skewX(30deg); }
```

This positions all the menu items where they should be, but now their contents are skewed. So you need to "unskew" them. By that, I mean that you apply a skew transform with the opposite angle. In this case, unskewing means applying `skewX(-30deg)`.

Still, the angle for the content is not right. You need to rotate it by half the central angle minus 90deg in this case. This means by `60deg/2 - 90deg = 30deg - 90deg = -60deg`.

The content (link in this case) should also be absolutely positioned such that its centre is at the point where you've set the `transform-origin` for its parent (`.menu-item`) you can give it any size you want, but if you want it to be circular, then you'll have to give it equal width and height and make sure that they aren't more than twice those of its parent (`.menu-item`).

Finally, you set `overflow: hidden` on `.menu-item` and you have a pie menu. If you want to cover the central part, you use a pseudo-element on the menu (`.menu-circ`).

Comment: I've added an explanation for the basic idea behind.

Comment: The explanation is very helpful for someone trying to build a menu with arbitary different angles for different elements, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at some of these properties:

- CSS 3 Transform - for the element rotations - [W3](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp)
- CSS 3 Transitions - to smoothly rotate the dial I suppose - [W3](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition.asp)
- CSS Hover selector - for the popup - [W3](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp)
- CSS 3 Clip - to shape the elements - [W3](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_clip.asp)

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial on creating css3 pie charts could help you: http://www.kylejlarson.com/blog/2011/how-to-create-pie-charts-with-css3/.

You could make all of the pie wedges be your buttons, then superimpose a smaller circle on the center of the wheel.